# Tool to convert from Swift to objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I know most of the questions are about converting from objective-c to swift, but I'm looking for a tool that can convert a swift code to objective-c. When searching all I find is objective-c to swift.

**Yes - I know I can put swift code inside objective-c project with a bridge-header - that's not what I'm looking for.**

I need a tool that converts swift code to objective-c code. Is there such thing?

Comment: Sorry, there was no one such tools available in market that converts your swift code into objective - c. You need to do on your hand.

Comment: I highly recommend against it. ObjC and Swift are completely different. It's like converting a bicycle into a car with a hammer.

Comment: Life would have been a lot easier if someone could give me a Obj-c to x-language converter. Would be no need to learn new languages xd

Comment: @NSNoob it's not that I don't need to learn swift. It's that I need obj-c code instead of swift - as mentioned I know I can use one in other. But instead of sitting down for hours now and translating one to another I was wondering if somehow I could avoid the pleasure.

Comment: developer82, I wrote a Perl script today that "translates" Swift to Obj C. It does so imperfectly and incompletely but avoids much of the manual labor. Unfortunately, I receive very imprecise stacktraces from Swift crashes, whereas Obj C crashes are more traceable, so I'm reluctantly converting some of my code in order to track down some persistent and elusive bugs. But since this topic is closed I cannot post code.

Comment: @NSNoob like this? https://objectivec2swift.com/#/home/main

Comment: @TeresaPeters Yeah I saw that about a year ago, sadly it doesn't work as precisely as one would like. But that's understandable because Swift isn't exactly similar to ObjC and most conversions require a human to do them right

Comment: I voted to reopen this because it's currently what I am looking for and it seems like a perfectly fine request to me.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There is no such tools for converting Swift code to Objective-C. There are some reasons. One is because Objective-C is a semantic subset of Swift, i. e. Objective-C doesn't have any equivalent of some fundamental features of Swift such as [Generics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic), [Algebraic data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type), [Pattern matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_matching) and other. Theoretically it is possible to make, but generated Objective-C code should be boilerplate and inefficient.

It is recommended to migrate your codebase to Swift to avoid technical debt there are many tools which can be used to [convert Objective-C to Swift](https://www.xspdf.com/resolution/52916558.html).

Comment: An optimizer could be implemented to make it less inefficient.  Just like any other compiler.

Comment: That there are no direct replacements ("equivalents") does not mean that it is intranslatable. For example generics are necessary in Swift because of its static nature. The equivalent of Objective-C is dynamic typing. It is the other way round: Dynamic typing is really difficult to translate into generics.